# What is assembly EnvDTE 8.0.0.0?

Tags: envdte

I made a small console app in VS 2010 and I just published it and went to install it on another pc (Win XP Sp3). The installer made me update the .Net framework, which I did and then when i went to run th second part which actually installs the app I am getting the following modal box:

Unable to install or run the application. the application requires that assembly EnvDTE Version 8.0.0.0 be installed in the Global Assembly cache (GAC) first.

Please contact your system administrator.

What in the world is EnvDTE v8.0.0.0????

This is a tiny app which does a small web call to an api and returns the results. I do make a DB call for a select and and update using some generated code from Codesmith/Nettiers (including enterprise Library). These files are referenced in the app though already.

Any ideas how to fix or work around this?

Comment: [EnvDTE is an assembly-wrapped COM library containing the objects and members for Visual Studio core automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), [How to install an assembly in GAC](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbide/thread/ce9368cd-ddbd-465a-a31f-e81ae159d197/)

Comment: It is installed with Visual Studio and or the Visual Studio SDK.

Answer (score 5):

EnvDTE.dll is, as Zabba said in his comment (not sure why he didn't answer with this) used to automate Visual Studio.  For some reason, you have added a reference to this in your project.

Open your solution, look at the References node in all your solution projects, and delete any reference pointing to EnvDTE.

It doesn't normally magically appear in your reference list; you either have to add it, or the project template you used to create your project referenced it, or you added an item whose template added this reference.